# How to create a raster "grading" several different layers (polygons)

Tags: qgis, raster, features, rank

So I have a bunch of different shapefiles loaded into qgis:

i.e.:
 - shape of poor soil quality
 - shape of cheap land areas
 - shape of poor weather areas

now I would like to create a map which "grades" the whole map, considering each one of these layers. For example: if the area is under poor soils it gets 0 points for that criteria, but if it is under cheap areas, it gets 10 points.. etc, etc..

any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can try to *paste* all the attributes in a single big shapefile (using **join attributes by location** throught **Processing**) and then classify the resulting file with the **Rule Renderer** style

Comment: I believe the term/process you're looking for is called weighted overlay.